# If the price is promotional, check if it is lower than original price

Tags: mysql, sql

### The goal

Within a list, I need to get the lowest possible price for each item.

### The problem

To get the lowest price of a product, I'm using this:

```
ROUND(CAST(MIN(`map`.`Product_Original_Price`) AS DECIMAL)/100,2) as `minProductPrice`
```

But, I want to check if this product has a `Product_Promotional_Price` (another column in the same table). If yes, check if it is lower than `Product_Price` — that is the original price.

Regardless of the result, return as `minProductPrice` as illustrated before.

So I ask: ***Which query turns this problem into solution?***

### Additional details

Sorry by the scarcity of details. My application aims to compare product prices. So, there is a stored procedure that returns a list of products. The result is:

[image: Image 01]

But `Product_Promotional_Price` of `Lava Roupas em Pó Omo Progress` is `5,50` and as you can see, is lower than `Product_Original_Price`. When things like that happen, I want to get `Product_Promotional_Price` instead of  `Product_Original_Price`.

### More details

To illustrate my problem:

> **Row 1**
>
> - `Product_Id` = 1
> - `Product_Name` = "iPhone 5"
> - `Market_Name` = "Walmart"
> - `Product_Original_Price` = "359.00"
> - `Product_Promotional_Price` = "319.00"
>
> **Row 2**
>
> - `Product_Id` = 1
> - `Product_Name` = "iPhone 5"
> - `Market_Name` = "Apple"
> - `Product_Original_Price` = "359.00"
> - `Product_Promotional_Price` = "0.00"
>
> **Row 3**
>
> - `Product_Id` = 1
> - `Product_Name` = "iPhone 5"
> - `Market_Name` = "BestBuy"
> - `Product_Original_Price` = "359.00"
> - `Product_Promotional_Price` = "299.00"

So, when I call my procedure, the `minProductPrice` for `iPhone 5` is `299.00`, by `BestBuy`.

Now can you all understand?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results to clarify your question.

Comment: Why are you doing `ROUND(CAST())`?  Why do you have `MIN`?  Are there multiple rows for each product?  Can you show your table schema and sample data?

Comment: `Regardless of the result, return as minProductPrice as illustrated before.` - Then why do you need to check the promotional price?

Comment: I'd recommend doing the `MIN` *after* you cast, not before: if your price is a character value (which it shouldn't be), the `MIN` of set `{"100", "22"}` will be `22`.

Comment: @EdGibbs Can you show me how?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Three markets can have the same product with different prices.

Comment: @Mubin Doesn't matter if the lowest price is from `Product_Original_Price` or `Product_Promotional_Price` — I just want the lowest price for this product.

Answer (score 3):

Try using LEAST(), it returns the lowest of the values passed to it:

```
SELECT Product_Id,
  MIN(LEAST(Product_Original_Price, Product_Promotional_Price)) as Best_Price
FROM Product_Price
GROUP BY Product_Id;
```

Take a look at this SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f380e0/1/0

Comment: Almost there, @bobwienholt! The result is right if the lowest price is `Product_Promotional_Price`, but the query returns me 0 if the `Product_Original_Price` for the specified product is lower than `Product_Promotional_Price`.

Comment: When there is no promotional price, what value is stored in that column?

Comment: So, a product without a promotional price would like like: Product_Original_Price = 3.50 Product_Promotional_Price = 3.50?

Comment: Nope. `Product_Id` = 1 | `Market_Name` = "Walmart" | `Product_Original_Price` = `4.50` | `Product_Promotional_Price` = `2.25` ~ `Product_Id` = 1 | `Market_Name` = "Bestbuy" | `Product_Original_Price` = `4.90` | `Product_Promotional_Price` = `2.05`

So, the `minProductPrice` for the `Product_Id = 1` is `2.05` by `BestBuy`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which DB you use but try something like this :

```
MIN(
ROUND(CAST(MIN(`map`.`Product_Price`) AS DECIMAL)/100,2) 
UNION
ROUND(CAST(MIN(`map`.`Product_Promotional_Price`) AS DECIMAL)/100,2)
) as `minProductPrice`
```

Comment: Can you really use `UNION` like that?  Care to explain this query a bit?

Comment: i can't in fact but like the select isn't write entirely, i write in consequence. In fact i thinked something like this : 
SELECT MIN(col) AS MinOfAllColumns
FROM 
  ( SELECT MIN(col1) AS col
    FROM MyTable
  UNION
    SELECT MIN(col2)
    FROM MyTable
  UNION
    SELECT MIN(col3)
    FROM MyTable
  ) AS tmp